# Beamer, print different layers

Tags: beamer, handout, layers

I have made this beamer document.

```
\documentclass[handout,a4]{beamer} 
\usepackage{handoutWithNotes}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
Question ? :\\
\onslide<2- | handout :0 >{ Answer 1\\}
\onslide<3- | handout :0 >{ Answer 2\\}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Is there a way to choose the layer I want to print out in pdf, in order to create a pdf with the question without the answer (I can do it with the code at the top) but also to be able (with smalls modifications) to create a document with the question AND the answer (I can't succeed with the code at the top)? If the solution is compatible with \pause that I use sometimes, it would be perfect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a great job for the `beameraudience` package. Comment/uncomment line 5 in the example below to switch between the  target audiences:

```
\documentclass[
handout
]{beamer} 

\usepackage[
audience=teacher
]{beameraudience}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
Question ? :\\
\justfor{teacher}{
\onslide<2->{ Answer 1\\}
\onslide<3->{ Answer 2\\}
}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

(if you'd like to automatically compile both versions, you could use the same techniques as described in https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=583 )

Comment: Great solution ! thank you. I will use it.
But I have already written a huge document with hundreds of <onslide 2->{blabla}
Is there a way to modify the \onslide command in order to include automatically the \justfor[teacher} command ?

Comment: @FabienC If your editor supports regex replacements, there is probably a way to replace them automatically, but I'm not really a regex expert, so don't ask me what the exact query for this would be. Do all your questions follow the pattern with the Q in the first slide and then answers? One could tell beamer to make a version which only shows the first slide for all frames.